# Hide password in settings.xml in jenkins for profiles

Tags: maven, jenkins, credentials

First we had a settings.xml like this:

```
<servers>
        <server>
            <id>test</id>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>secret1</password> 
        </server>
</servers>
<profiles>
    <profile>
            <id>flyway.help</id>
            <properties>
                <flyway.placeholders.db.user>user</flyway.placeholders.db.user>
                <flyway.placeholders.db.password>secret2</flyway.placeholders.db.password>
            </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The username and password are in plain text.
Than we used the credentials plugin inside our global `settings.xml` so we could hide the username and password of our server.

[image]

It's now like this:

```
<servers>
        <server>
            <id>test</id>
        </server>
</servers>
```

It's pointing to the ID test. This works well. 
But how can we hide the passwords we have inside our profile section. Between the flyway tags?

Comment: Do not use a profile better use the server configuration as in the documentation stated... https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/

Comment: @khmarbaise hmm seems like your right. Is it common to avoid profiles in the settings.xml?

Comment: Based on the usage via server entries you can use the credentials Store of Jenkins...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes I did for the server section. But this won't work for passwords of profiles which are set in the settings.xml so I should avoid profiles in the settings.xml?

Comment: You should avoid profiles in settings.xml just use server id where you can use the credentials store of jenkins. ...